# Can I upload a file to my server using a form and POST in HTML?

Tags: html, post

I want to create a way that people can upload images to an images folder on my server using an HTML form and the input type file, I thought that the only way it was ever possible to add a file to my server was to FTP in there and drag it in. Is there a straight forward way I could create a form that would allow someone to select an image and just upload it to my folder?

Comment: You'll need a server-side language like PHP to do this.

Comment: I can use PHP or ColdFusion if I knew how, or if it was possible. Thanks.

Comment: PHP, then you can start here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straight forward example from w3schools. Comes with an example HTML and PHP script

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: This provided me with a great example, that was easy to understand, for a beginner like me this was perfect, don't know why I couldn't find it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

See [POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for an introduction. There are plenty of file upload examples on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+upload).

Answer (score 1):

You could find more information here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need some type of script on the server to handle the file.  I know that you can google for and find at least a couple of PHP scripts because I had to do it a few years ago.  The script can also be useful in that it can change the name of the file so that duplicate files do not overwrite each other.

[Sample upload script](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)